# Is there any Management Identity (Azure) functionality in Digital Ocean?

Tags: authorization, cloud, digital-ocean, azure-managed-identity

I'd like to know if there is any Managed Identity (Azure) functionality in Digital Ocean?

Are there any, and if not, maybe there are commonly used approaches to achieve the same functionality?, in particular:

1. Authorization of recourse between each other in the scope of VPC (DigitalOcean)
2. Authorization of users to access resources (via IDE), analogy- it's possible in Azure through `DefaultAzureCredential()` to access anything that has Managed Identity.
3. The rest of the features.

Thank you.

Checked on Google + looked into the official documentation (DO)